# The constructor for local control is being called, but the control is not shown

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am following a WPF tutorial [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/user-control-in-wpf/) on how to show control content on a Window , and I fail to get the local control to show as intended.

Here's my MainWindow.xaml code

```
<Window x:Class="McXamlLib.MainWindow"
        x:Name="Window"

        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:McXamlLib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="565" Width="310">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <local:XAMLFileBrowser />
    </Grid>
</Window>

namespace McXamlLib
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my local control (XamlFileBrowser.xaml) code

```
<UserControl x:Class="McXamlLib.XAMLFileBrowser"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:McXamlLib"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 

             x:Name="XAMLFileBrowserControl"
             d:DesignHeight="39" d:DesignWidth="397">


    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="42" Width="504">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.352"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.648"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="FBCTextBox" Margin="4,10.313,137, 4.001" Text ="TextBox"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TextChanged="FCTextBox_TextChanged" />

        <Button x:Name="FBCButton" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,8,13,4" Width="111" Content="Browse" Grid.Column="1"
                Click="FBCButton_Click" />


    </Grid>
</UserControl>
namespace McXamlLib
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class XAMLFileBrowser : UserControl
    {
        public XAMLFileBrowser()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var nameTextBox = FBCTextBox.Name;
        }


        public string FileName
        {
            get { return FBCTextBox.Text; }
            set { FBCTextBox.Text = value; }
        }

        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> FileNameChanged;

        private void FCTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            if (FileNameChanged != null)
                FileNameChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        private void FBCButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            if (openFileDlg.ShowDialog() == true)
                this.FileName = openFileDlg.FileName;
        }
    }
}
```

I can break into `public XAMLFileBrowser()` constructor class, and check the value for `nameTextBox`, but I just can't get the control to show as it should:

[image]

Instead, I got a blank MainWindow screen.

Any reason why?

Comment: So the exact problem is that the MainWindow is not loading the local:XAMLFileBrowser control? Or it's not loading the content properly?

Comment: @NahuelIanni, I have no idea-- all I got was a blank MainWindow UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of your columns are set to pixels and therefore, occupying a really small space.

If you modify it to percentage, which I assume was your intention, it shows correctly:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"></ColumnDefinition>
<ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*"></ColumnDefinition>
```

[image]

You can check [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/layouts-with-xaml) on how proportional units and layouts work in XAML.

Answer (score 1):

You have set columns of the grid in `XAMLFileBrowser` to have width under one pixel so anything in that grid (textbox and button) are collapsed under one pixel and not visible.
For start, remove `Width` values completely and you will see control. Then adjust them until you get exactly what you want.